# CakePHP: make global routes for admin plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, routes, admin

So I started making the admin panel of our site as a plugin. And I'm able to redirect every request like domain.com/admin or domain.com/admin/users or domain.com/admin/pages/edit/5 - to the appropriate controller and action from the admin plugin.
Like this one:

```
 Router::connect('/admin', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
 Router::connect('/admin/users/list', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'list'));
```

But this means I will have to write separate route for almost each URL ??? or actually - for each action ... So - is there a way to set it globally? ...

For example:

```
 Router::connect('/admin/users/*', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'users'));
```

Or even better:

```
 Router::connect('/admin/*', array('plugin' => 'admin'));
```

Cause the last two examples didn't work at all ...

EDIT: the CakePHP version is the latest at the moment - 2.4.1.

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using.

Comment: OK, I'll try to remember ... :) ... and I edited my question ;) ...

Answer (score 1):

Normally you shouldn't have to create such routes for plugins, the basic mapping works out of the box, ie in case your plugin is named `admin`, then `/admin/users/list` will automatically map to plugin `admin`, controller `users`, action `list`.

An exception is your `/admin` route, by default this would look for `index` on `AdminController`. So for mapping to `index` on `IndexController` you'll need a custom route like the one in your question:

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Apart from this it should work as is in case you don't have any other preceding rules that will override the default behaviour, something like `Router::connect('/*', ...)` for example. In case there *are* such rules and you cannot change them, then this is how you could connect the basic routes of your plugin:

```
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'admin'));
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/*', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/admin/*', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Note that this needs to be placed *before* the other routes that override the default behaviour!

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

On a side note, `list` as an action name will probably not work, this should throw a parser error as `list` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php). So you in case this isn't just an example you'll need an extra route for that if you want to use `/list` as the action name in the URL.

Comment: Hmm ... well, this is true for the controllers and the actions ... indeed ... :) ... but for the starting page of the admin panel - it is not ... ... so if I try only domain.com/admin - and then it asks me to create class AdminController.php in Plugin/Admin/ ...

Comment: Right, I've added the necessary route in the code example, but forgot to mention that it's not part of the standard routing. I'll update my answer.